# Artix 7 Block RAM instantiation in Vivado 2015.2

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, ram, vivado, artix-series-fpga

Ok I'm trying to create a Block RAM instantiation in true dual port type. I have used the IP catalog and block memory generator in Vivado, which has given me a giant file that I now need to strip down to the parts that I need. This is my first time using internal block ram or ram at all. My question is what do I need out of the first code to make it work in Vivado. The second peace of code is what I have been working with which gave me many errors which I posted in another thread multi-driver net found.

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

LIBRARY blk_mem_gen_v8_2;
USE blk_mem_gen_v8_2.blk_mem_gen_v8_2;

ENTITY blk_mem_gen_0 IS
   PORT (
      clka : IN STD_LOGIC;
      rsta : IN STD_LOGIC;
      ena : IN STD_LOGIC;
        wea : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0);
       addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);
       dina : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
       douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
       clkb : IN STD_LOGIC;
       rstb : IN STD_LOGIC;
      enb : IN STD_LOGIC;
          web : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0);
        addrb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);
          dinb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
       doutb : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0)
        );
       END blk_mem_gen_0;

       ARCHITECTURE blk_mem_gen_0_arch OF blk_mem_gen_0 IS
        ATTRIBUTE DowngradeIPIdentifiedWarnings : string;
        ATTRIBUTE DowngradeIPIdentifiedWarnings OF blk_mem_gen_0_arch:                                            

       COMPONENT blk_mem_gen_v8_2 IS
       GENERIC (
       C_FAMILY : STRING;
       C_XDEVICEFAMILY : STRING;
      C_ELABORATION_DIR : STRING;
       C_INTERFACE_TYPE : INTEGER;
       C_AXI_TYPE : INTEGER;
       C_AXI_SLAVE_TYPE : INTEGER;
       C_USE_BRAM_BLOCK : INTEGER;
      C_ENABLE_32BIT_ADDRESS : INTEGER;
     C_CTRL_ECC_ALGO : STRING;
      C_HAS_AXI_ID : INTEGER;
      C_AXI_ID_WIDTH : INTEGER;
      C_MEM_TYPE : INTEGER;
      C_BYTE_SIZE : INTEGER;
      C_ALGORITHM : INTEGER;
      C_PRIM_TYPE : INTEGER;
      C_LOAD_INIT_FILE : INTEGER;
     C_INIT_FILE_NAME : STRING;
      C_INIT_FILE : STRING;
     C_USE_DEFAULT_DATA : INTEGER;
      C_DEFAULT_DATA : STRING;
      C_HAS_RSTA : INTEGER;
     C_RST_PRIORITY_A : STRING;
     C_RSTRAM_A : INTEGER;
  C_INITA_VAL : STRING;
  C_HAS_ENA : INTEGER;
  C_HAS_REGCEA : INTEGER;
  C_USE_BYTE_WEA : INTEGER;
  C_WEA_WIDTH : INTEGER;
  C_WRITE_MODE_A : STRING;
  C_WRITE_WIDTH_A : INTEGER;
  C_READ_WIDTH_A : INTEGER;
  C_WRITE_DEPTH_A : INTEGER;
  C_READ_DEPTH_A : INTEGER;
  C_ADDRA_WIDTH : INTEGER;
  C_HAS_RSTB : INTEGER;
  C_RST_PRIORITY_B : STRING;
  C_RSTRAM_B : INTEGER;
  C_INITB_VAL : STRING;
  C_HAS_ENB : INTEGER;
  C_HAS_REGCEB : INTEGER;
  C_USE_BYTE_WEB : INTEGER;
  C_WEB_WIDTH : INTEGER;
  C_WRITE_MODE_B : STRING;
  C_WRITE_WIDTH_B : INTEGER;
  C_READ_WIDTH_B : INTEGER;
  C_WRITE_DEPTH_B : INTEGER;
  C_READ_DEPTH_B : INTEGER;
  C_ADDRB_WIDTH : INTEGER;
  C_HAS_MEM_OUTPUT_REGS_A : INTEGER;
  C_HAS_MEM_OUTPUT_REGS_B : INTEGER;
  C_HAS_MUX_OUTPUT_REGS_A : INTEGER;
  C_HAS_MUX_OUTPUT_REGS_B : INTEGER;
  C_MUX_PIPELINE_STAGES : INTEGER;
  C_HAS_SOFTECC_INPUT_REGS_A : INTEGER;
  C_HAS_SOFTECC_OUTPUT_REGS_B : INTEGER;
  C_USE_SOFTECC : INTEGER;
  C_USE_ECC : INTEGER;
  C_EN_ECC_PIPE : INTEGER;
  C_HAS_INJECTERR : INTEGER;
  C_SIM_COLLISION_CHECK : STRING;
  C_COMMON_CLK : INTEGER;
  C_DISABLE_WARN_BHV_COLL : INTEGER;
  C_EN_SLEEP_PIN : INTEGER;
  C_USE_URAM : INTEGER;
  C_EN_RDADDRA_CHG : INTEGER;
  C_EN_RDADDRB_CHG : INTEGER;
  C_EN_DEEPSLEEP_PIN : INTEGER;
  C_EN_SHUTDOWN_PIN : INTEGER;
  C_DISABLE_WARN_BHV_RANGE : INTEGER;
  C_COUNT_36K_BRAM : STRING;
  C_COUNT_18K_BRAM : STRING;
  C_EST_POWER_SUMMARY : STRING
  );
   PORT (
      clka : IN STD_LOGIC;
      rsta : IN STD_LOGIC;
      ena : IN STD_LOGIC;
      regcea : IN STD_LOGIC;
      wea : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0);
      addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);
      dina : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
      douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
      clkb : IN STD_LOGIC;
      rstb : IN STD_LOGIC;
      enb : IN STD_LOGIC;
      regceb : IN STD_LOGIC;
      web : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0);
      addrb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);
      dinb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
       doutb : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
      injectsbiterr : IN STD_LOGIC;
       injectdbiterr : IN STD_LOGIC;
       eccpipece : IN STD_LOGIC;
       sbiterr : OUT STD_LOGIC;
       dbiterr : OUT STD_LOGIC;
        rdaddrecc : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0);
       sleep : IN STD_LOGIC;
      deepsleep : IN STD_LOGIC;
         shutdown : IN STD_LOGIC;
       s_aclk : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s_aresetn : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_awid : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_awaddr : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_awlen : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_awsize : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_awburst : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_awvalid : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_awready : OUT STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_wdata : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_wstrb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_wlast : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_wvalid : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_wready : OUT STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_bid : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_bresp : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_bvalid : OUT STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_bready : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_arid : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_araddr : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_arlen : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(7 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_arsize : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_arburst : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_arvalid : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_arready : OUT STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_rid : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_rdata : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(17 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_rresp : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 DOWNTO 0);
  s_axi_rlast : OUT STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_rvalid : OUT STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_rready : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_injectsbiterr : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_injectdbiterr : IN STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_sbiterr : OUT STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_dbiterr : OUT STD_LOGIC;
  s_axi_rdaddrecc : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(9 DOWNTO 0)
   );
   END COMPONENT blk_mem_gen_v8_2;

   ATTRIBUTE X_CORE_INFO : STRING;
   ATTRIBUTE X_CORE_INFO OF blk_mem_gen_0_arch: ARCHITECTURE IS "blk_                                                                                                  
     ATTRIBUTE CHECK_LICENSE_TYPE : STRING;
    ATTRIBUTE CHECK_LICENSE_TYPE OF blk_mem_gen_0_arch : ARCHITECTURE IS      
    ATTRIBUTE CORE_GENERATION_INFO : STRING;
   ATTRIBUTE CORE_GENERATION_INFO OF blk_mem_gen_0_arch: ARCHITECTURE IS            
   ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO : STRING;
   ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF clka: SIGNAL IS  ce:bram:1.0 BRAM_PORTA   ;
   ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF rsta: SIGNAL IS ace:bram:1.0 BRAM_PORTA ;
   ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF ena: SIGNAL IS 
   ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF wea: SIGNAL IS 
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF addra: SIGNAL IS 
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF dina: SIGNAL IS  
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF douta: SIGNAL IS 
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF clkb: SIGNAL IS 
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF rstb: SIGNAL IS  
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF enb: SIGNAL IS  
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF web: SIGNAL IS  
  ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF addrb: SIGNAL IS  
 ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF dinb: SIGNAL IS  
 ATTRIBUTE X_INTERFACE_INFO OF doutb: SIGNAL IS 
BEGIN
   U0 : blk_mem_gen_v8_2
GENERIC MAP (
  C_FAMILY => "artix7",
  C_XDEVICEFAMILY => "artix7",
  C_ELABORATION_DIR => "./",
  C_INTERFACE_TYPE => 0,
  C_AXI_TYPE => 1,
  C_AXI_SLAVE_TYPE => 0,
  C_USE_BRAM_BLOCK => 0,
  C_ENABLE_32BIT_ADDRESS => 0,
  C_CTRL_ECC_ALGO => "NONE",
  C_HAS_AXI_ID => 0,
  C_AXI_ID_WIDTH => 4,
  C_MEM_TYPE => 2,
  C_BYTE_SIZE => 9,
  C_ALGORITHM => 1,
  C_PRIM_TYPE => 1,
  C_LOAD_INIT_FILE => 0,
  C_INIT_FILE_NAME => "no_coe_file_loaded",
  C_INIT_FILE => "blk_mem_gen_0.mem",
  C_USE_DEFAULT_DATA => 0,
  C_DEFAULT_DATA => "0",
  C_HAS_RSTA => 1,
  C_RST_PRIORITY_A => "CE",
  C_RSTRAM_A => 0,
  C_INITA_VAL => "0",
  C_HAS_ENA => 1,
  C_HAS_REGCEA => 0,
  C_USE_BYTE_WEA => 0,
  C_WEA_WIDTH => 1,
  C_WRITE_MODE_A => "WRITE_FIRST",
  C_WRITE_WIDTH_A => 18,
  C_READ_WIDTH_A => 18,
  C_WRITE_DEPTH_A => 1024,
  C_READ_DEPTH_A => 1024,
  C_ADDRA_WIDTH => 10,
  C_HAS_RSTB => 1,
  C_RST_PRIORITY_B => "CE",
  C_RSTRAM_B => 0,
  C_INITB_VAL => "0",
  C_HAS_ENB => 1,
  C_HAS_REGCEB => 0,
  C_USE_BYTE_WEB => 0,
  C_WEB_WIDTH => 1,
  C_WRITE_MODE_B => "WRITE_FIRST",
  C_WRITE_WIDTH_B => 18,
  C_READ_WIDTH_B => 18,
  C_WRITE_DEPTH_B => 1024,
  C_READ_DEPTH_B => 1024,
  C_ADDRB_WIDTH => 10,
  C_HAS_MEM_OUTPUT_REGS_A => 0,
  C_HAS_MEM_OUTPUT_REGS_B => 0,
  C_HAS_MUX_OUTPUT_REGS_A => 0,
  C_HAS_MUX_OUTPUT_REGS_B => 0,
  C_MUX_PIPELINE_STAGES => 0,
  C_HAS_SOFTECC_INPUT_REGS_A => 0,
  C_HAS_SOFTECC_OUTPUT_REGS_B => 0,
  C_USE_SOFTECC => 0,
  C_USE_ECC => 0,
  C_EN_ECC_PIPE => 0,
  C_HAS_INJECTERR => 0,
  C_SIM_COLLISION_CHECK => "ALL",
  C_COMMON_CLK => 0,
  C_DISABLE_WARN_BHV_COLL => 0,
  C_EN_SLEEP_PIN => 0,
  C_USE_URAM => 0,
  C_EN_RDADDRA_CHG => 0,
  C_EN_RDADDRB_CHG => 0,
  C_EN_DEEPSLEEP_PIN => 0,
  C_EN_SHUTDOWN_PIN => 0,
  C_DISABLE_WARN_BHV_RANGE => 0,
  C_COUNT_36K_BRAM => "0",
  C_COUNT_18K_BRAM => "1",
  C_EST_POWER_SUMMARY => "Estimated Power for IP     :     3.1193 mW"
)
enter code here
PORT MAP (
  clka => clka,
  rsta => rsta,
  ena => ena,
  regcea => '0',
  wea => wea,
  addra => addra,
  dina => dina,
  douta => douta,
  clkb => clkb,
  rstb => rstb,
  enb => enb,
  regceb => '0',
  web => web,
  addrb => addrb,
  dinb => dinb,
  doutb => doutb,
  injectsbiterr => '0',
  injectdbiterr => '0',
  eccpipece => '0',
  sleep => '0',
  deepsleep => '0',
  shutdown => '0',
  s_aclk => '0',
  s_aresetn => '0',
  s_axi_awid => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 4)),
  s_axi_awaddr => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 32)),
  s_axi_awlen => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 8)),
  s_axi_awsize => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 3)),
  s_axi_awburst => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 2)),
  s_axi_awvalid => '0',
  s_axi_wdata => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 18)),
  s_axi_wstrb => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 1)),
  s_axi_wlast => '0',
  s_axi_wvalid => '0',
  s_axi_bready => '0',
  s_axi_arid => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 4)),
  s_axi_araddr => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 32)),
  s_axi_arlen => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 8)),
  s_axi_arsize => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 3)),
  s_axi_arburst => STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(TO_UNSIGNED(0, 2)),
  s_axi_arvalid => '0',
  s_axi_rready => '0',
  s_axi_injectsbiterr => '0',
  s_axi_injectdbiterr => '0'
);
END blk_mem_gen_0_arch;

enter code here
```

The next peace of code I was given to work with. This peace of code gives me multi drivers net found errors. It was also written for a Spartan 3 chip. I need one for an artix 7 chip. Thanks

```
   RAMB16_S18_S18_inst : RAMB16_S18_S18
   generic map (
      INIT_A => X"00000", --  Value of output RAM registers on Port A at up
    INIT_B => X"00000", --  Value of output RAM registers on Port B at startup
  SRVAL_A => X"00000", --  Port A ouput value upon SSR assertion
  SRVAL_B => X"00000", --  Port B ouput value upon SSR assertion
  WRITE_MODE_A => "WRITE_FIRST", --  WRITE_FIRST, READ_FIRST or NO_CHANGE
  WRITE_MODE_B => "WRITE_FIRST", --  WRITE_FIRST, READ_FIRST or NO_CHANGE
  SIM_COLLISION_CHECK => "ALL", -- "NONE", "WARNING", "GENERATE_X_ONLY", "ALL
  -- The follosing INIT_xx declarations specify the intiial contents of the RAM
  -- Address 0 to 255
  INIT_00 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_01 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_02 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_03 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_04 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_05 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_06 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_07 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_08 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_09 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_0A => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_0B => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_0C => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_0D => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_0E => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_0F =>                X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  -- Address 256 to 511
  INIT_10 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_11 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_12 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_13 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_14 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_15 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_16 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_17 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_18 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_19 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_1A => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_1B => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_1C => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_1D => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_1E => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_1F => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  -- Address 512 to 767
  INIT_20 => X"00000000000000004703CEC28D8100282E2E8037903190319031903100000000",
  INIT_21 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_22 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_23 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_24 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_25 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_26 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_27 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_28 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_29 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_2A => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_2B => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_2C => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_2D => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_2E => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_2F => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  -- Address 768 to 1023
  INIT_30 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_31 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_32 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_33 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_34 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_35 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_36 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_37 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_38 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_39 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_3A => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_3B => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_3C => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_3D => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_3E => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INIT_3F => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  -- The next set of INITP_xx are for the parity bits
  -- Address 0 to 255
  INITP_00 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INITP_01 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  -- Address 256 to 511
  INITP_02 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INITP_03 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  -- Address 512 to 767
  INITP_04 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INITP_05 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  -- Address 768 to 1023
  INITP_06 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  INITP_07 => X"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000")


port map (
  DOA => DOA,      -- Port A 16-bit Data Output
  DOB => dataout,      -- Port B 16-bit Data Output
  DOPA => DOPA,    -- Port A 2-bit Parity Output
  DOPB => DOPB,    -- Port B 2-bit Parity Output
  ADDRA => ADDRA,  -- Port A 10-bit Address Input
  ADDRB => addr,  -- Port B 10-bit Address Input
  CLKA => CLKA,    -- Port A Clock
  CLKB => ram_clk,    -- Port B Clock
  DIA => DIA,      -- Port A 16-bit Data Input
  DIB => datain,      -- Port B 16-bit Data Input
  DIPA => DIPA,    -- Port A 2-bit parity Input
  DIPB => DIPB,    -- Port-B 2-bit parity Input
  ENA => ENA,      -- Port A RAM Enable Input
  ENB => ram_enable,      -- PortB RAM Enable Input
  SSRA => '0',    -- Port A Synchronous Set/Reset Input
  SSRB => ram_reset,    -- Port B Synchronous Set/Reset Input
  WEA => WEA,      -- Port A Write Enable Input
  WEB => we       -- Port B Write Enable Input
 );
```

Comment: You don't need a BlockRAM IP core to generate a dual port RAM. It's possible to use circa 20 generic VHDL code lines. See the Vivado HDL guide for usage examples.

Comment: I have used example code from this document                      Xilinx 7 Series FPGA and Zynq-7000 All Programmable SoC Libraries Guide for HDL Designs
UG768 (v14.7) October 2, 2013

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a generic VHDL code snippet is much smaller....

Example: [PoC.mem.ocrom.tdp](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/mem/ocram/ocram_tdp.vhdl)

```
entity ocram_tdp is
    generic (
        A_BITS      : positive;
        D_BITS      : positive
    );
    port (
        clk1 : in   std_logic;
        clk2 : in   std_logic;
        ce1 : in    std_logic;
        ce2 : in    std_logic;
        we1 : in    std_logic;
        we2 : in    std_logic;
        a1   : in   unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);
        a2   : in   unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);
        d1   : in   std_logic_vector(D_BITS-1 downto 0);
        d2   : in   std_logic_vector(D_BITS-1 downto 0);
        q1   : out std_logic_vector(D_BITS-1 downto 0);
        q2   : out std_logic_vector(D_BITS-1 downto 0)
    );
end entity;


architecture rtl of ocram_tdp is
    constant DEPTH : positive := 2**A_BITS;
        signal ram          : ram_t;
        signal a1_reg       : unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);
        signal a2_reg       : unsigned(A_BITS-1 downto 0);
begin
        process (clk1, clk2)
        begin   -- process
            if rising_edge(clk1) then
                if ce1 = '1' then
                    if we1 = '1' then
                        ram(to_integer(a1)) <= d1;
                    end if;
                    a1_reg <= a1;
                end if;
            end if;
            if rising_edge(clk2) then
                if ce2 = '1' then
                    if we2 = '1' then
                        ram(to_integer(a2)) <= d2;
                    end if;
                    a2_reg <= a2;
                end if;
            end if;
        end process;
        q1 <= ram(to_integer(a1_reg));      -- returns new data
        q2 <= ram(to_integer(a2_reg));      -- returns new data
end architecture;
```

See the linked file for more features:

- read RAM content from disk at synthesis time
- switch to Altera primitives if synthesized with Quartus-II

Comment: I need to use the internal block ram because I'm reading and writing to the block ram with the vhdl code and reading and writing from the block ram with C code.

Comment: [Vivado Design Suite  User Guide Synthesis](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2015_3/ug901-vivado-synthesis.pdf) (UG901, page 94 RAM HDL Coding Techniques.  If you have a Xilinx login there's a link for downloading HDL (VHDL and Verilog) examples. The examples in UG901 show among other things how to infer block RAM.

Comment: This code maps to BlockRAM. That's why it's call on-chip RAM  (ocram).

Comment: ok. I still need the instantiation part right????

Comment: Or you copy the `process` into your file ...

Comment: Thanks for the help I'm going to have to do more research and reading. I'm not fallowing you when you say add process it to your file?